# how to create a message box that displays how many in tems are in the input file

Tags: c++, user-interface, struct, count

I am working on this GUI in C++ that should ask for the path of an input .txt file and the output path then create a formatted output file. I'm trying to make a message box come up after I click the "Report" button that will count the number of items in the input file and display that number. I'm doing it as a struct and I'm not sure how to make it work.Please give me a hand on this. This is all from my Form.h file. I"m gonna skip all of the window generated code to safe space.

```
#pragma once

 //declare structure and variables at the top of form code


#pragma region Global Declarations

struct PetData
{
int IdNumber;
char PetType[25];
 //Count and display the number of items in the linked list
int CountItems;
PetData * Link;
};
PetData *Headpointer = NULL;

ifstream DataFile;
ofstream FileOut;

void InsertItem ( int, char[], PetData* );
void OutputItem ( PetData*);



 #pragma endregion


namespace GilleyFinalExamSample {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

//include these libraries
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
```

now Im going to get down to the stuff i added

```
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void ExitButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
              Application::Exit();
         }
private: System::Void InputFileBox_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
         InputFileBox->Clear();
         OutputFileBox->Clear();
     }
private: System::Void CreateFileButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
         PetData *CurrentRecordPointer;

         int InitIdNumber =0;
         char InitPetType[25] = "\0";

        // get the filename and store it in inputFilename

        char* InputFileName;

         InputFileName = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(InputFileBox->Text);

         DataFile.open ( InputFileName );

         //validation check

         if (!DataFile )
         {
             Application::Exit( );

         }//end of if stmt

    //get filename and store in OutputFileName

         char* OutPutFileName;

         OutPutFileName = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi( OutputFileBox->Text);

         FileOut.open (OutPutFileName );

         //validation check

         if (!FileOut)
         {
             Application::Exit();

         }//end of if stmt

         //priming read

         DataFile >> InitIdNumber;
         DataFile.ignore( );
         DataFile.get (InitPetType, 7 );

         while ( DataFile )
         {
            CurrentRecordPointer = new PetData;
            InsertItem(InitIdNumber, InitPetType, CurrentRecordPointer);
            Headpointer = CurrentRecordPointer;

             DataFile >> InitIdNumber;
             DataFile.ignore( );
             DataFile.get (InitPetType, 7 );

         }//end of while loop

         OutputItem ( Headpointer );
         FinalMessage->Visible=true;

         //cleanup
         DataFile.close( );
         FileOut.close( );
         delete CurrentRecordPointer;
         Headpointer = NULL;

     }//end brace of create file button

  //define Insert and output functions

     void InsertItem ( int InitIdNumber, char InitPetType[ ], PetData* CurrentRecordPointer )
     {
         CurrentRecordPointer->IdNumber = InitIdNumber;
         strcpy_s (CurrentRecordPointer->PetType, InitPetType);
         CurrentRecordPointer->Link = Headpointer;

         return;
     }//close brace of InsertItem

     void OutputItem ( PetData *FirstRecord )
     {
         FileOut << "       Pet Data    " << endl << endl;
         FileOut << "   Id Number    Pet Type   " << endl;

         while (FirstRecord != NULL)
         {
             FileOut << FirstRecord->IdNumber
                     << "       "
                     <<FirstRecord->PetType
                     <<endl;
             FirstRecord = FirstRecord->Link;
         }//end of while

         return;
     }//close brace of OutputItem Function
};
}
```

Don't mind that it says "final exam" This is just practice for a final. thank you so much for your help

Comment: None of that code seems relevant to displaying a message box.

Comment: Looks more like *managed* C++.

Comment: I'm not sure where to implement the code to display the counting message box, so i just put most of my code

Comment: an old code i wrote used this     MessageBox::Show ("Listed Printed To Output File \n"
     + FirstRecordPointer->CountItems () + " Items Were Printed",
     "Report Created", MessageBoxButtons::OK,
     MessageBoxIcon::Information);